# Spanning List vs Column Space + Vector Space? (Definitions)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, terminology, definition

Could someone please clarify for me the difference between a spanning list and a column space? Is it the same thing? The definitions that I have in front of me are as follows:

- A list of vectors in a vector space is a **spanning list** of that
  vector space if every vector in the vector space can be written
  as a linear combination of the vectors in that list
- The **column space** of a matrix $A$ is all the linear combinations of its column vectors, which is essentially the span of those vectors.

Also, I want to make sure I understand the difference between a vector space and a linear subspace. Once again, I am given two definitions and I want to know if these are interchangeable terms:

- A **linear subspace** contains the zero-vector, is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.
- A **vector space** is a nonempty set of vectors which is closed under the vector space operations.

I know a span is a linear subspace by the definition provided above, and of course by that, so is a column space. But are they also a vector space? Is a spanning list a vector space as well? Would appreciate if someone would help me get my terminology right here. Thanks!

Comment: A spanning list is not a vector space, but the set of linear combinations of vectors in the list is.  The columns vectors of a matrix are the spanning list of the column space, but you could have a spanning list not in the context of matrix columns

Comment: A linear subspace is part of a larger vector space

Comment: For example, {$(1,0), (0,1)$} is a spanning list for $\Bbb R^2$, but {$(1,0), (0,1)$} is not a vector space since it does not contain $(2,0)$, $(1,1)$, etc.  (Its *span* does.)  Are you familiar with the term subset?  A subset is a legitimate, bona fide set, but calling it a subset emphasizes that it is part of a larger set.  Subset is to set as subspace is to space

Answer (score 1):

A spanning list is not a vector space, but the set of linear combinations of vectors in the list is.  For example, $\{(1,0),(0,1)$} is a spanning list for $\Bbb R^2$, but {$(1,0),(0,1)$} is not a vector space, since it does not contain $(2,0), (1,1)$, etc., though its *span* does.

A linear subspace is part of a larger vector space.  A linear subspace is a vector space, but calling it a subspace emphasizes that it is part of a larger space, just as a subset is a set contained by a larger set.

The columns vectors of a matrix are the spanning list of the column space, but you could have a spanning list not in the context of matrix columns.